# creating swift generic for CGPoint and CGVector

Tags: ios, xcode, generics, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to create a very simple generic for cgpoint and cgvector.  I just want to plugin my variable, and multiply x,y or dx,dy by two

```
func dblPt<T>(inout point: T){
    // double cgpoint, or cgvector

}
```

my problem is i cant think of how to reference x or y, vs dx, and dy.  I haven't written anything using generics.  What's the best way of accomplishing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a generic function, write an overloaded function - that is, do it twice, but with cgvector and cgpoint. You can call them the same name and call them with either type, but have different bodies internally.

Comment: so basically just write the function twice with the same name, but different return types.  thats fine i guess.  just doesnt seem real DRY

Answer (score 2):

How would you like to use protocol/extension?
Here is an example.

```
protocol VectorConvertible {
    func toVector() -> CGVector
    class func fromVector(vec: CGVector) -> Self
}

extension CGVector: VectorConvertible {
    func toVector() -> CGVector { return self }
    static func fromVector(vec: CGVector) -> CGVector { return vec }
}

extension CGPoint: VectorConvertible {
    func toVector() -> CGVector { return CGVectorMake(x, y) }
    static func fromVector(vec: CGVector) -> CGPoint { return CGPointMake(vec.dx, vec.dy) }
}

func dblPt<V: VectorConvertible>(inout v: V) {
    let vec = v.toVector()
    v = V.fromVector(CGVectorMake(vec.dx * 2, vec.dy * 2))
}
```

Comment: this is interesting.. but more code than i expected.  still cool to look at how i could accomplish things through the generics route